# Is it possible to accept user input in Processing.js?

Tags: javascript, html, input, processing

In my HTML project, I have a `<canvas></canvas>` tag with some processing.js code, and I wish to accept user input. Is there a function that can do that?

Comment: You mean like create a field in the canvas to insert text? Also, processing.js is outdated and has been succeeded by p5.js

Comment: Yeah, and where can I learn p5.js?

Comment: This is the site for p5.js, it provides p5.js and documentation, with tutorials. https://p5js.org/